# why does my data not appear whenever i reload the page

Tags: python, django

i made a search function for getting date from my data in django, but when i refreshed, all the data from my table is gone

this is my views.py

```
def index(request):
info = Info.objects.all()
query = request.GET.get("q")
if query:
    info = info.filter(
        Q(Fname__icontains=query) |
        Q(Diagnosis__icontains=query)
    ).distinct()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'info': info})
else:
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'info': info})
```

this is what is showing in my
[website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC3Cx.png)

my model.py

```
class Info(models.Model):
Fname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
Lname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
Mname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
DOB = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True)
Age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
Address = models.CharField(max_length=30)
DateIn = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True)
DateOut = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True)
Diagnosis = models.CharField(max_length=30)
Physician = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('patient_info:index.html', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

def __str__(self):
    return self.Lname + ' ' + self.Fname
```

and my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #patient_info/
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    #patient_info/add
    path('add/', views.PatientCreate.as_view(), name='patient-add'),
    #patient_info/edit/pk
    path('edit/<int:pk>/', views.PatientUpdate.as_view(), name='patient-edit'),
    #patient_info/delete/pk
    #path('delete/<int:pk>/', views.PatientDelete.as_view(), name='patient-delete'),
]
```

please help, thank you

Comment: Do you have `query` on every reload? Basically `?q=xxx` in your URL.

Comment: @PanwenWang, yes but the problem is, even without a query yet, the data won't load